# update problem using "apt-get update"

Tags: command-line, updates, kde

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

[image]

the command I gave was

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

what I have to do? (I'm under kubuntu 11.10)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like that you have added some extra repositories that no longer exit.

Remove this repositories:

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Look for all lines containing a url to ppa.launchpad.net and comment them out by adding a '#' infront of the line.

Then try again.

Edit if you do not like vim and want to use you can use any other editor, maybe you'd like kedit for example:

```
sudo kedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Answer (score 1):

procede to eliminate these ppa's :

1. [nvidia-vdpau](https://launchpad.net/~nvidia-vdpau/+archive/ppa) doens't exist in oneric.

> ```
> sudo ppa-purge ppa:nvidia-vdpau/ppa
> ```

1. sevenmachine doens't exist in oneric.

> ```
> sudo ppa-purge ppa:sevenmachines/flash
> ```

. [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

(see Removing a PPA with ppa-purge)...

Answer (score 0):

You should simply remove that ppa packages that do not fetch anymore.